# Constrained Minimization Closed Form if available or R suggestions

Tags: r, optimization

Please note that I am trying to minimize the following function. If closed form solutions are not available, pointers on how to do this in R would be much appreciated.

$$
\underset{\left\{ S_{i}\right\} }{\min}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{i=K}\left\{ \max\left(\theta S_{i}+\alpha_{i},0\right)\left(\sum_{j=i}^{j=K}S_{j}\right)\right\} \right]
$$

Here, $\sum_{i=1}^{i=K}S_{i}=W$ ; $S_{i},W\geq0$ and $\theta,\alpha_{i}\in R$,
that is they are real numbers.

As an example, for $K=3$ we get,
$$
\underset{\left\{ S_{1},S_{2},S_{3}\right\} }{\min}\left[\max\left(\theta S_{1}+\alpha_{1},0\right)\left(S_{1}+S_{2}+S_{3}\right)+\max\left(\theta S_{2}+\alpha_{2},0\right)\left(S_{2}+S_{3}\right)+\max\left(\theta S_{3}+\alpha_{3},0\right)\left(S_{3}\right)\right]
$$

Please let me know if the above is not clear or if you need any further details.

Comment: In view of your example, the general expression should be $\underset{\left\{ S_{i}\right\} }{\min}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{i=K}\left\{ \max\left(\theta S_{i}+\alpha_{i},0\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{j=i}S_{j}\right)\right\} \right]$, no ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thanks for noticing this. What you say is indeed true. I have corrected this now. Please also note, I slightly modified the example as well since there was a mistake earlier.